# My script is acting inappropriately

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script to search column A for 'Assay' and copy (0,2) and paste it at the end of each row until there is a blank row. This works fine on most of my groups, but one group, in particular, is acting inappropriately.

It copies the cell as expected and only pastes it to the first two rows. I don't know how to correct it.

Here's a screenshot of my data:
[image: Here's a screenshot of my data]

Here is the code I'm using. I have a feeling that it has to do with there being blanks in the rows, but I don't know how to correct the script.

```
Sub AddDescriptive()
  Dim Assays as Range, Assay As Range, Group As Range, P As Range
  Set Assays = FindAll(Columns("A"),"Assay")
  If Assays Is Nothing Then
     Exit Sub
  End If

  'Visit each
  For Each Assay In Assays
  'Get the group
  Set Group = Assay.Offset(, 2)
  'Assign to column P
  Set P = Intersect(Assay.CurrentRegion.EntireRow, Columns("P"))
  'Write the group into column P
  P.Value = Group.Value
 Next
End Sub

Function FindAll(ByVal Where As Range, ByVal What, _
     Optional ByVal After As Variant, _
     Optional ByVal LookIn As XlFindLookIn = xlValues, _
     Optional ByVal LookAt As XlLookAt = xlWhole, _
     Optional ByVal SearchOrder As XlSearchOrder = xlByRows, _
     Optional ByVal SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, _
     Optional ByVal MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
     Optional ByVal SearchFormat As Boolean = False) As Range
 'Find all occurrences of What in Where (Windows version)
  Dim FirstAddress As String
  Dim c As Range
 'From FastUnion:
  Dim Stack As New Collection
  Dim Temp() As Range, Item
  Dim i As Long, j As Long

 If Where Is Nothing Then Exit Function
 If SearchDirection = xlNext And IsMissing(After) Then
 'Set After to the last cell in Where to return the first cell in Where in 
   front if it match What
 Set c = Where.Areas(Where.Areas.Count)
'BUG in XL2010: Cells.Count produces a RTE 6 if C is the whole sheet
'Set After = C.Cells(C.Cells.Count)
 Set After = c.Cells(c.Rows.Count * CDec(c.Columns.Count))
End If
 Set c = Where.find(What, After, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, _
 SearchDirection, MatchCase, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)
 If c Is Nothing Then Exit Function
 FirstAddress = c.Address
 Do
 Stack.Add c
 If SearchFormat Then
  'If you call this function from an UDF and _
    you find only the first cell use this instead
 Set c = Where.find(What, c, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, _
    SearchDirection, MatchCase, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)
Else
  If SearchDirection = xlNext Then
    Set c = Where.FindNext(c)
  Else
    Set c = Where.FindPrevious(c)
  End If
End If
'Can happen if we have merged cells
If c Is Nothing Then Exit Do
Loop Until FirstAddress = c.Address
'FastUnion algorithm © Andreas Killer, 2011:
'Get all cells as fragments
 ReDim Temp(0 To Stack.Count - 1)
 i = 0
 For Each Item In Stack
 Set Temp(i) = Item
 i = i + 1

Next
'Combine each fragment with the next one
j = 1
Do
For i = 0 To UBound(Temp) - j Step j * 2
  Set Temp(i) = Union(Temp(i), Temp(i + j))
Next
j = j * 2
Loop Until j > UBound(Temp)
'At this point we have all cells in the first fragment
Set FindAll = Temp(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Have you verified that the selected, anticipated region, is recognized when stepping through the code?  Though the screenshot helps a little, it leaves out a bit of information such as what was in Column A after the first instance you see "40" (frmo the *correct* example).  It sort of looks like your FindAll is being based on contiguous cells, so the Assay, CA, space, CA, breaks the continuity.

Comment: The `CurrentRegion` from the "Assay" cell in your screenshot is 2 rows and 4 columns wide, so using `CurrentRegion` is not going to work.  You seem to have data in every relevant row in column N (and in column O).  Would it be possible to use `Range("P" & Assay.Row & ":P" & Range("N" & (Assay.Row + 1)).End(xlDown).Row).Value = Group.Value`?

Comment: That's it Cyril! The FindAll function that I found online is being broken by the spaces between Assay, CA, space.....CA. Is there a way to correct this code? I can pick apart small scripts but this is a behemoth!

Comment: `FindAll` is simply returning all of the individual cells containing `"Assay"` within column A.  It isn't worried about blank rows at all.

Comment: YowE3K, I wouldn't know where to test that range theory. What would you replace with this?

Comment: `I have a script to search column A for 'Assay' and copy (0,2) and paste it at the end of each row until there is a blank row` Aha, if this is true then your code is working fine, because you're telling it to stop at the first blank cell in column A. What you really should be telling it is to stop *when there are no more rows*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with `FindAll`.  (It is simply returning a range containing the cells in column A which contain the text `"Assay"`, so might be returning the range `$A$2,$A$345,$A$1235,$A$1365`.)

Your problem is actually with the use of `Assay.CurrentRegion` which will return only the current region which includes the cell referred to by `Assay`, and that region is only two rows and four columns in size.

Based on the data in your screenshot, it appears you want to place the value `"APPEARANCE"` into column P, starting from the row in which `"Assay"` was found, and ending at the row prior to the next blank cell in column N.

That can be achieved by changing

```
  Set P = Intersect(Assay.CurrentRegion.EntireRow, Columns("P"))
```

to be

```
  Set P = Range("P" & Assay.Row & ":P" & Range("N" & (Assay.Row + 1)).End(xlDown).Row)
```

Comment: You Sir are a scholar and gentleman. Thank you for the help.I thought for sure the problem was in the FindAll function. Glad I posted.